# Aspose cells 'Σ Values' shown in Row for pivot table

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, aspose, aspose-cells

I am using aspose-cells-17.9 java version. I am trying to create a pivot table from the raw data sample shown below.

<kbd>Affiliate</kbd> <kbd>Impression</kbd><kbd>Clicks</kbd>    
<kbd>abc</kbd>    <kbd>1000</kbd>     <kbd>2000</kbd>   
and so on.

If i try to create pivot table with the following code

```
    PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables.get(index);

    // Unshowing grand totals for rows.
    pivotTable.setRowGrand(true);

    // Dragging the first field to the row area.
    pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.ROW, 0);

    // Dragging the second field to the column area.
    pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.COLUMN, 1);

    // Dragging the third field to the data area.
    pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.DATA, 2);
```

I am getting the following output as selected values.

[image]

But what I am expecting is as follows

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following sample code, its comments and screenshot. As you can see in screenshot, the output Excel file has the pivot table as per your needs. Please remember Σ-values field is represented by **PivotTable.getDataField()** and this is the change I have made in your code.

**Java**

```
PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables.get(index);

// Unshowing grand totals for rows.
pivotTable.setRowGrand(true);

// Dragging the first field to the row area.
pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.ROW, 0);

// Dragging the second field to the data area.
pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.DATA, 1);

// Dragging the third field to the data area.
pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.DATA, 2);

// Dragging the Σ-values field to the column area.
pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.COLUMN, pivotTable.getDataField());
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Worked as expected!!

Comment: This is the code I use to create and add the pivot table to existing worksheet
`pivotTables.add("=A1:C12", "E3", "PivotTable2");` . How to add the pivot table to new worksheet, your comment will be helpful.

Comment: You will add it in second sheet and refer to pivot table data in first sheet as "Sheet1!A1:C12". Please see the following line of code, it adds the pivot table in second sheet and the data is inside first sheet ----   int index = sheet2.getPivotTables().add("Sheet1!A1:C12", "E3", "PivotTable2"); ---- Thanks and regards.